# Google Place ID Not Working

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using the Easy Google Places Reviews Wordpress plugin on my clients site. The plugin uses the Google Places ID to pull in business reviews to three different location contact pages. They have three locations in Quincy, Cambridge, and Saugus, MA. Cambridge and Saugus are pulling in the reviews with no issues, Quincy, however, is not. Everything on the Quincy page is the same as the other two location pages. For some reason the Google Place ID is not working. I contacted the plugin developer who said it might be an error on the Google side of things since the plugin is working for the other two locations. Has anyone heard of this happening before or have any idea why the Google Place ID wouldn't work? Is there a way to get a different ID number? Any help would be really appreciated! Thanks so much!

Comment: What is the place ID that doesn't work?

Comment: Hi, The info is Lux Dental Inc.
Place ID ChIJIULRmEFj44kR7iABUN4woHM
505 Washington St, Quincy, MA 02169, USA

Comment: When I execute places API request https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?key=MY_API_KEY&placeid=ChIJIULRmEFj44kR7iABUN4woHM, I can see reviews. Not sure what the plugin is doing.

Comment: It's very strange. I have Google Maps for the Quincy location on the same page as the reviews and the map is working fine. The reviews are working fine on the other pages for Cambridge and Saugus through the plugin as well. It seems to be just Quincy that won't show the reviews. I've tried copying the code and duplicating the page for the other locations, and then putting the Quincy Place ID in, to test it, and still nothing. Is there any way I can test the Place ID? Thanks for your help @xomena!

Comment: Problem solved! Turns out it was something to do with the wp theme. I had to reinstall the theme and wp files due to some issues, and afterwards the Quincy location worked perfectly. Thanks for all the help!